# React Native Expo: React Map view Crashed after build Apk but local development ok

Tags: react-native, expo

React Native Expo: React Map view Crashed after build Apk but local development ok.Geocoding is also ok but problem rise after apk build .I do not use any google maps api key as local development is no problem,
How to resolve my issue,Please help,I am new in react native